# Unable to create Virtual Machine on Windows Azure

Tags: azure, virtual-machine

The problem is that every time I try to create Virtual Machine it starts provisioning and stucks there (status never changes from Starting (Provisioning)).

After I refresh the Management Portal page (or sign out and in again) that VM disappear. I have been trying to create VMs with different configurations in different regions for two days now.

I have attached screenshot with the state of VM in which it stays infinitely.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out the problem was in browser - Azure Management Portal compatability. I have Chrome version 28.0.1500.95 on Windows 8, 64x. Everything worked well in IE10.